# Desura sales experiences

Tags: distribution, sales

Does anyone know of (or have) an experience selling an indie title through [Desura](http://www.desura.com/)? How does it compare with other typical indie game distribution avenues?

Answer (score 1):

Swing Swing Submarine published [a bit of info for their Blocks That Matters sales](http://www.swingswingsubmarine.com/2012/02/23/blocks-that-matter-in-figures/). It appears that Steam and Indievania brought them more revenue than Desura.